# Different languages

Tags: java, java-me, nokia

I'm developing an app for the nokia e75 using j2me. What is a good way of showing content in the right lang? I don't think that java beans are an option.

Just to be clear; the problem isn't to know what the lang is of the device, but how to generate the right content knowing the lang the user uses.

thx

Comment: Do you mean internationaonalization? Maybe a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495808/javame-internationalization-i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using following strategy:

1. Storing resources in Java properties files, like "KEY=Value"
2. Separate resources for each language, like: messages_en, messages_fr, messages_gr and so on
3. Use in code instead of static Strings references to Keys from properties
4. Detect language using

   System.getProperty("microedition.locale");
5. After locale detection load appropriate language resource

Comment: I have followed a similar approach

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of detecting the user's language is to read the language set for the phone.

```
System.getProperty("microedition.locale");
```

Implementation of Localization/Internationalization depends on the framework you are using.

- [Here is a good article describing it](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-global/?ca=dnt-515)
- [Here is another one](http://jan.newmarch.name/i18n/j2me/j2me.html)

Comment: "Just to be clear; the problem isn't to know what the lang is of the device"

Comment: ok, I'll remove the downvote if you provide the right answer :)

Comment: @Valentin Rocher now you may proceed :)